Как добавить ответ с кнопки в базу данных?
Подскажите пожалуйста, не могу сообразить, как мне текст с кнопки добавить в базу данных SQL.
Есть код кнопки:
kb_age = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
ib1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='< 18',
                               callback_data='easy_age')
ib2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='18-30',
                               callback_data='warn_age')
ib3 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='> 30',
                               callback_data='hard_age')
kb_age.add(ib1).add(ib2).add(ib3) ```

Есть код обработки кнопок:


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='easy_age')
async def save_age(call: types.CallbackQuery):
await bot.send_message(chat_id=call.from_user.id, text='Ты еще совсем юный! А как давно ты "В игре"?', reply_markup=in_game)
await call.message.delete()
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='warn_age')
async def save_age(call: types.CallbackQuery):
await bot.send_message(chat_id=call.from_user.id, text='Хороший возраст! А как давно ты "В игре"?', reply_markup=in_game)
await call.message.delete()
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='hard_age')
async def save_age(call: types.CallbackQuery):
await bot.send_message(chat_id=call.from_user.id, text='Отлично! А как давно ты "В игре"?', reply_markup=in_game)
await call.message.delete() ```
И есть таблица:
async def db_start():
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user("
                #"user_id INTEGER,"
                "age TEXT,"
                "game TEXT, "
                "money TEXT, "
                "feel TEXT)")
    db.commit() ```

Пользователю предлагается на выбор три кнопки. При любом ответе он получает следующее сообщение. Но не могу понять, как именно мне схватить его ответ и записать его в поле "age" в моей таблице.

Буду признательна за помощь!




Начните с освоения разметки Markdown. Приведите сообщение в порядок.
